# What is this 3rd viewpoint on Absolute and Relational Space known as?

Tags: metaphysics, leibniz

So I've been obsessing about [absolute and relative motion](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/):

> What is the nature of motion in physical theories and theorizing, and
> is there any significance to the distinction between ‘absolute’ and
> ‘relative’ motion?

However, I've reached a different conclusion, though closer to Leibniz.

If object A interacts with object B we attempt to construct a geometry where the interaction is considered local.

To elaborate a bit more:

For example, if gas molecule A interacts with gas molecule B. Then we perceive the interaction as local. Now, if you see molecule A and B near each other but not interacting can we say they are near each other? Yes, you shot photons at A and photons at B so there is an entire chain of locality (you included) which enables you to say A is next to B. Note this works for quantum mechanics quite well.

Is it meaningful to say things are light-like or space-like in say QFT? Yes, you can make this statement but notice any field has a vacuum energy and a particle is essentially an excitement of the field (Also, we do not know non-pertubative QFT as well as we'd like to)

What is this viewpoint known as? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: If you want to learn about QFT, the right forum is the physics stack exchange

Comment: @nielsnielsen I strongly doubt they would let me post this there? (it would get closed). But if you think here is not the right place for it either I suppose I can delete it?

Comment: Oh no, please do not delete, I am just saying that the *technical* answer has more to do with physics than with philosophy.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I personally feel these kind of questions (extensions of Newton vs Leibniz) are generally not well received: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91064/rovellis-preferred-emergent-frame-a-new-stance-on-newtons-bucket-vs-leibniz

Comment: I have no idea what this has to do with the absolute/relative debate, or what you think makes it philosophy.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Newton's whole view point was that there existed a background(/geometry) independent of everything. Leibniz did not.

Comment: Still have no idea what you think is the third alternative between relative and absolute space.

Comment: "If object A interacts with object B we attempt to construct a geometry where the interaction is considered local" - For me the interactions are fundamental